# Startup script doesn't work in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, startup

I was struggling with changing my new mouse sensitivity. Finally I found proper solution:
`xinput --set-float-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.8`. Now I need to run it on system startup. I found that I have to create .conf file in /etc/init. I've done it in following way (in file named changeMouseSensibility.conf):

```
description "Set mouse sensitivity"
start on startup
task
script
xinput --set-float-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.8
end script
```

and after that I'm executing:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/init/upstart-job changeMouseSensibility
```

but unfortunately it does not work. After system restart mouse sensibility remains with old speed.

I also tried with cron: now after executing `crontab -e` I have following line:

```
@reboot xinput --set-float-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.8
```

but it also does not work for me.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

check :
Linux Cron utility is an effective way to schedule a routine background job at a specific time and/or day on an on-going basis

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: Thanks for response, but I need solution for my concrete case. As I mentioned I've tried with cron but it does not work for me.